# Definition of $k$-transposition group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

In [A monster tale: a review on Borcherds’ proof of monstrous moonshine conjecture](http://preprint.impa.br/FullText/ReyesFigueroa__Mon_Jun__7_14_37_57_BRST_2010/MonsterTale.pdf), a $k$-transposition group is defined as follows.

> Recall that a $k$-transposition group $G$ is one generated by a
>   conjugacy class $K$ of involutions, where the product $gh$ of any two
>   elements of $K$ has order at most $k$.

I am trying to understand this. Does it mean that $G$ is generated by a multiplication of $k$ transpositions? For example: is $\langle (1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6)\rangle$ a transposition group?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a $1$-transposition group.

Comment: @DerekHolt, so, how many transpositions we need to have a $k$-transposition group?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you are getting confused by the word transpositions. This has nothing to do with transpositions $(i,j)$ as elements of $S_n$. You have written down the definition yourself. It is concerned with involutions, which are elements of order $2$ in any group.

Comment: @DerekHolt, isn't a transposition which is an element of $S_n$ is also an involution?

Comment: Yes of course. An involution is an element of order $2$, and a transposition has order $2$. By taking $K$ to be the set of all transpositions in $S_n$, we see that $S_n$ is a $3$-transposition group.

Comment: @DerekHolt, is there any involution which is not a transposition element in $S_n$?

Comment: Yes, the example you gave, $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)$ is an involution but not a transposition. It is a product of three transpositions.